# Change from a cell, the main array DataSource of the table view (pointers)

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

In my table view, every cell sets itself up in his own Class, it lookes like so:

```
//Table view Class:

    if (!cell) 
    {
        cell = (MainFeedCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MainFeedCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    }
    cell = [MainFeedMODEL tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPathWihTable:self.tableView andArrayOfData:self.feedArray andIndexPAth:indexPath andViewController:self];

//Cell Class:

    self.labelTime.text = [NSString dateCalculationFor:self.feedObject.createdDate];
    [self.labelLikes setText:self.feedObject.likesCount];
    [self.labelComments setText:self.feedObject.commentsCount];
```

It all works great until I would like to change something in the main Array of data, the dataSource Array of my `UITableView`.

Then I need to start delegating between the cell and the main `UITableView`, but I'm quite sure there is a better way.

How do I send a pointer, that if the cell changes is, it changes the original array.

For instance I'll call this:

```
 [self.feedArray setObject:@"SomthingElse" atIndexedSubscript:3];
```

From the cell, and it will change the value of the original array that was sent.

Thanks!

Comment: Key-Value-Observing of ReactiveCocoa come to mind. I would prefer the former because I don't know about ReactiveCocoa yet.

Comment: Thank you this is very useful, what do you mean by former? Delegate?

Comment: No, Key-Value-Observing is different from the delegate pattern: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Comment: Yah i know, but i did not understand what you meant by saying "  I would prefer the former because I don't know about ReactiveCocoa yet". Never mind this helped me a lot thanks

Comment: I meant, I would prefer KVO and not ReactiveCocoa.